# Control a small motor

Tags: relay

Is it possible to control a small motor without using any relay, and just resistors. The motor is super small maybe 1cm in width and 2cmd in height and is from an old RC plane. I tried using a relay but i think its to big compared to the motor.

Comment: What sort of motor are you talking about?

Comment: @joan It's a super small RC plane motor.

Comment: Could you post  a photo or describe the connections?  A normal DC motor will have two loose wires, a servo motor will have 3 wires termintated in a special 3 pin plug.  A brushless DC motor tends to have 3 loose wires.  It's only a servo you can drive without additional hardware.

Comment: @joan It's 2 (red, black) cables very thin, thinner than the normal GPIO cables. Okey, why is that?

Comment: It sounds like an ordinary DC motor.  If it spins when you connect the wire to a battery of about 5V (or *carefully* to the Pi's 5V and ground pins) then it is an ordinary DC motor.  The gpios can only supply a few milliamps.  A motor will need more.  Also the back EMF from the motor can kill a Pi gpio and/or the Pi when the motor is switched off.  You can buy a L9910S based motor driver board for a pound or so from eBay.  That will let you drive the motor backwards and forwards (and control the speed using PWM).  Hobby servos have in-built motor driver boards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends upon the type of motor you have.

You can't control a DC motor (what we generally think of as a motor) from the Pi without additional hardware.

Neither can you control a stepper motor without additional hardware.

However your motor may be a servo motor as they are quite often used in RC models.

A servo motor you can control from the Pi without additional hardware.